# From Select option to multiple checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, database, checkbox

So, I have this code where you can choose a specific sub-genre of music. Right now you can only choose a single sub-genre; how can I code it so you can choose multiple sub-genres (maybe via checkbox) that can be inserted into a database?

```
    $day = $_POST["day"];
    $month = $_POST["month"];       
    $year = $_POST["year"];     
    $main = $_POST["main"];     

            $ne = "SELECT * FROM genre WHERE genre='0' AND main='$main'";
            $ne_query_run = mysql_query($ne);
    ?>
    <?php
            echo '<form action="site.php?koncert&fire" method="POST">';
            echo '<input type="text" name="day" class="hide" value="'.$day.'"/>';
            echo '<input type="text" name="month" class="hide" value="'.$month.'"/>';
            echo '<input type="text" name="year" class="hide" value="'.$year.'"/>';                                     echo '<input type="text" name="main" class="hide" value="'.$main.'"/>';
            echo '<select name="sub">';
            while($neo = mysql_fetch_assoc($ne_query_run)){

            $sub = $neo['sub'];

            echo '<option value="'.$sub.'">'.$sub.'</option';

            echo'</select><br /><br />';
            }
            echo '<input type="submit" name="submit"/>';
            echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Be careful: your variable `$main` is subject to SQL injection!

Comment: try this <select name="sub" multiple="multiple">

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make use of checkboxes,  you may exchange

```
        echo '<select name="sub">';
        while($neo = mysql_fetch_assoc($ne_query_run)){

        $sub = $neo['sub'];

        echo '<option value="'.$sub.'">'.$sub.'</option';

        echo'</select><br /><br />';
        }
```

with

```
        while($neo = mysql_fetch_assoc($ne_query_run)){
           $sub = $neo['sub'];
           echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$sub.'" value="true">'.$sub.'</input>';
        }
```

Assuming that you have a sub called `MySub`, later on you may check if the this sub selected by `$_POST['MySub']`.

If your subs are not uniquely named, but you want to use the genre's id instead, I would recommend using

```
        while($neo = mysql_fetch_assoc($ne_query_run)){
           $sub = $neo['sub'];
           $id= $neo['id'];
           echo '<input type="checkbox" name="sub['.$id.']" value="true">'.$sub.'</input>';
        }
```

On POSTing back, `$_POST['sub']` then will be an array (see `print_r($_POST['sub'])`), where the ID is the key. The value of the array will be `"true"` (string - not a boolean!) in case the checkbox has been checked.

Comment: What i ended up doing was :

echo '<input type="checkbox" name="sub[]" value="'.$sub.'"><label>'.$sub.'</label><br>';

     $result = implode(", ",$_POST['sub']); and put it in a database

So lets say i have the two picked subgenre were Alternativ and Indie Rock. How can i make sure that only bands that signed up with thoose sub genre can Interact with this given submitted form post?

Answer (score 0):

Use  `<select multiple>`

```
   <select multiple>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>


     echo '<select name="sub" multiple>';
            while($neo = mysql_fetch_assoc($ne_query_run)){

            $sub = $neo['sub'];

            echo '<option value="'.$sub.'">'.$sub.'</option';

            echo'</select><br /><br />';
      }
```